# When building procedure, get error "SELECT not valid input at this position"

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Figured this would be a common issue, but after scanning the interviews for the last hour, apparently not.

In a nutshell, I'm attempting to put a common query that is used into a procedure. Here's what I have so far.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS splitColumnsDelimiter;

CREATE PROCEDURE splitColumnsDelimiter(IN DELIMITER VARCHAR(5))
BEGIN
SELECT
  sometbl.id,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(sometbl.name, '|', numbers.n), '|', -1) name
FROM
  (SELECT 1 n UNION ALL SELECT 2
   UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4) numbers INNER JOIN sometbl
  ON CHAR_LENGTH(sometbl.name)
     -CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(sometbl.name, '|', ''))>=numbers.n-1
ORDER BY
  id, n

END;
```

The query itself works like a charm. It seems however that adding any code to turn it into a procedure makes the workbench that i'm using pop up errors all over the place. From examples I've found on le internet, what I have should(?) be fine, but obviously not, so anyone happen to know where I might have been led astray, and where I can be enlightened? Figure this has to be pretty easy to do.

EDIT: Here is the code that seems to have at least removed the error from occurring.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS splitColumnsDelimiter;

DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE splitColumnsDelimiter()
BEGIN

SELECT
      sometbl.id,
      SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(sometbl.name, '|', numbers.n), '|', -1) name
    FROM
      (SELECT 1 n UNION ALL SELECT 2
       UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4) numbers INNER JOIN sometbl
      ON CHAR_LENGTH(sometbl.name)
         -CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(sometbl.name, '|', ''))>=numbers.n-1
    ORDER BY
      id, n;

END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Executing a CALL splitColumnsDelimiter; now works as expected, returning the SQL table returns that I expected to see.

Comment: why is the delimiter a parameter of the stored procedure

Comment: @meda it seemed to be that way for every example of building a procedure that I saw. I'm wondering if the examples I found were any good.

Comment: I dont think you should pass DELIMITER as a parameter and even if you named it differently it is not being used

Comment: @meda ok removed it and the corresponding $$ at the end of the code listed above, but sadly the issue remains

Comment: You still haven't told us what the error is.

Comment: @Sander “SELECT not valid input at this position” is the error that is reported by the MySQL Workbench software

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS splitColumnsDelimiter;
 CREATE PROCEDURE splitColumnsDelimiter()
   BEGIN

    SELECT
      sometbl.id,
      SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(sometbl.name, '|', numbers.n), '|', -1) name
    FROM
      (SELECT 1 n UNION ALL SELECT 2
       UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4) numbers INNER JOIN sometbl
      ON CHAR_LENGTH(sometbl.name)
         -CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(sometbl.name, '|', ''))>=numbers.n-1
    ORDER BY
      id, n;

   END //
 DELIMITER ;
```

If you meant to put a parameter for the separator `|` then put in a parameter and use it instead of hardcoding it, you should not call it `DELIMITER`

EDIT:

I read in your [comments that you are using workbench](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31680557/when-building-procedure-get-error-select-not-valid-input-at-this-position/31685552?noredirect=1#comment51314500_31680557), just keep the procedure definition like the following:

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE splitColumnsDelimiter()
   BEGIN

    SELECT
      sometbl.id,
      SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(sometbl.name, '|', numbers.n), '|', -1) name
    FROM
      (SELECT 1 n UNION ALL SELECT 2
       UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4) numbers INNER JOIN sometbl
      ON CHAR_LENGTH(sometbl.name)
         -CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(sometbl.name, '|', ''))>=numbers.n-1
    ORDER BY
      id, n;

   END
```

Remove the `DELIMITER` and `DROP` statement

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The code posted caused a similar error (CREATE instead of SELECT like above), but removing the first line and the // after END seem to resolve. See above edit.

Comment: ok tried that and it's coming up with missing semicolon for the ORDER BY and END statements. Re-adding the Delimiter statements resolve the issue.